# How to extract keys from nested JSON

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to extract keys from nested json using spark.

I have below JSON

```
{
    "predicates": {
        "API_No": "http://www.oilandgas.com/api_no",
        "Facility_ID": "http://www.oilandgas.com/facility_id"
    },
    "prefixes": {
        "API_No": "http://www.oilandgas.com/api_no/ ",
        "Facility_ID": "http://www.oilandgas.com/facility_id/ "
    },
    "relations": {
        "API_No": [
            "Facility_ID",
            "County"
        ]
    },
    "grahName": "http://www.oilandgas.com/data"
}
```

I wrote below code read json

```
val df = spark.read.option("multiline", "true").json("path/to/above/json")
df.select(explode(array(col("relations")))).columns.foreach(println)
```

I want to get key in 'relations' as 'API_No' from dataframe.

Thanks In advance.

Comment: Can you please clarify by elaborating the requirement? Or can you please specify the output that you want?

Comment: What did the print statement print?

Comment: print statement is printing 'col'

Comment: @VihitShah I want to get out put all keys inside nested json like 'API_No' inside 'relations' . Here in above example only one key its result as Array("API_No") if there are multiple keys then Array("API_No", .....)

Comment: The answer seems correct...right!? @JoshiSrikanthRao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting the key in `relations` as `API_No` from dataframe you have to just project (select) just `relations` key. Since type of `relations` key is `struct`, by projecting it you can get the desired result. Like the following:

```
df.select("relations.*").columns.foreach(println)
```

It will give the following result:

```
API_No
```

I hope it helps!

Comment: I want to get Array of keys inside nested json like In above example as Array("API_No") without using "API_No"

Comment: Edited my answer. Just replace `API_No` with `*` to get all key(s).